# Open Graph data not rendering even though test tool works

Tags: jekyll, facebook-opengraph

I've got a Jekyll site setup where I've been trying to enable open graph meta tags for sharing on social. I began using the jekyll markup approach to implement dynamic OG meta tags, however they didn't work - so I resorted to hardcoding them.

I've confirmed my tags are present using this tool - https://coveloping.com/tools/open-graph-tag-tester

Yet when I try to share the site I'm not seeing a preview.

The meta data is present - view-source:http://amillionwordsforcharity.org/ But I'm obviously missing something. I also have Twitter card meta data in there too, can they co-exist or should OG meta data work in Twitter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should test your site [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

So, looks like your *Facebook APP id* is not configured well, so correct it, or simply remove it.

Another thing is that, you have placed same details in your all blog post, but it should be various for each page.

Use this front matter in your *jekyll* blog

```
layout: post
title: Your Blog Post/page title
description: Write unique description for each webpage.
ogimg: http://www.example.com/assest/image/photo0.png
```

Now, you need to add this *meta tags* in your head section.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{page.title}}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{{page.url | replace:'index.html','' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}}}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{page.description}}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{page.ogimage}}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Also, I have seen *double slash* in your blog URL (click on continue reading and you will see double slash in permalink), so fix that also in your config permalink option.

Comment: Fantastic advice. I found the Facebook test tool cached changes making it hard to trouble shoot on the fly, I now have a working version to work from, so feel more confident making the changes you suggest. E.G reverting back to a dynamic OG specification on each page and using front matter markdown to fill that out. Thanks for the other tips too, I'd noticed them but not considered them a big deal. Will sort!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)